# Que tipo de droga é "algodão"?

Tags: significado, gíria

A música "Loja (canção Do Carocho)", do grupo Da Weasel, fala sobre drogados ("carochos") e drogas.
Nela fala-se de "branca", "castanha", "prata", "bombas"... e também de "um algodão":

> Miúdas que quase que fazem [favores sexuais] em troca de **um algodão**.
>   Quase que fazem, [nada], fazem mesmo.
>   Caras e corpos de 40 anos que na verdade viveram apenas metade desse tempo.

O que é este "um algodão"?
Um tipo de droga? Uma quantidade?

Comment: Isto não merecerá o tag «Portugal»?

Comment: Talvez, @Jacinto, mas como saber? Se calhar merece a tag «Lisboa», porque nunca a tinha ouvido no Norte... ;-) (Serei demasiado "fozeiro"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo [um léxico](http://padrejulio.do.sapo.pt/droga/lexico.htm) que encontrei, o algodão é usado como um filtro na preparação de drogas injetáveis:

> Algodão utilizado como filtro na preparação da dose injectável de droga. A partir de um algodão usado pode fazer-se uma lavagem e recuperar assim  resíduos para uma nova dose (filtro).

A estrofe parece falar desta "lavagem" para aproveitar os restos, por um tóxico-dependente desesperado sem outras perspetivas de "arranjar uma dose".